# NodeJS TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value while parsing query

Tags: node.js

My index.js file looks like this

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var parseUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);

  var path = parseUrl.pathname;

  var parsedurl = url.parse(req.url, true);

  // Get the path
  var path = parsedurl.pathname;
  var trimmedPath = path.replace(/^\/\/+$/, '');

  var queryStringObject = parsedurl.query;
  // Get the HTTP Method
  var method = req.method.toLowerCase();

  // Send the response
  res.end('Hello World\n');

  // Log the request path
  console.log(
    'Request received on path:' +
      trimmedPath +
      'with method' +
      method +
      'query' +
      queryStringObject
  );
});

server.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log(`Server is listening kamal`);
});
```

My terminal
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5XSo.png)
I don't know why I am facing this error, to the best of my knowledge the code looks correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate objects to strings. You could explicitly convert the `queryStringObject` to a string (e.g., by using `JSON.stringify`), but since you aren't using the parsed querystring and just want to display, you could just avoid parsing the querystring when you parse the URL:

```js
var parseUrl = url.parse(req.url);
// Second arg (true) removed ---^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error states that you are trying to use an `object` as a primitive value `string, number, boolean`.

[`url.parse(req.url,true).query`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-access-query-string-parameters/) returns an object, eg:`{ foo: 'bad', baz: 'foo' }`. You cannot simply add it to a string without prior conversion.

Try using `JSON.stringify()` :

```
 console.log('Request received on path:'+trimmedPath+'with method'+method+'query'+JSON.stringify(queryStringObject));
```

or maybe takeout individual query params and add to the string (based on your use case).